# KnockoutJS remove item from observable array. Item is listitem within ul, which was generated by foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using KnockoutJS, how can I remove an item from an observable array? I want to be able to click on the listitem, and remove the item from the array (and thereby the list).

The code sample below reports: 'this.expertise is undefined'.

Do I need to define some sort of expertise object, and then call it from within there?

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: expertise">
    <li data-bind="text: Key, click: $parent.removeExpertise"></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function AppViewModel() {

            this.removeExpertise = function (expertise) {
                this.expertise.remove(expertise);

            };

            this.expertise = ko.observable([
                { Key: 'Charles', Value: 'Charlesforth' },
                { Key: 'Denise', Value: 'Dentiste' }
            ]);
        }

        // Activates knockout.js
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you call a method from the child, `this` will be set to the child rather than `$parent`.

There are many ways to ensure that `removeExpertise` is called with the appropriate value for `this`.  An easy way is to use `.bind`.

It would look like:

```
this.removeExpertise = function (expertise) {
    this.expertise.remove(expertise);
}.bind(this);
```

Also, you will want `expertise` to be an `observableArray` rather than an `observable`, as an `observableArray` exposes array manipulation methods including a `remove` function.

Comment: what does the .bind do?  The word bind is all over their docs, so I may be overlooking it

Comment: .bind returns a new function that wraps the original function and calls it with a consistent value for "this".  In this case, you want it to always use the instance of `AppViewModel` as `this`.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: this would be nice:

viewModel.items.remove("id", 1);
viewModel.items.remove("name", "Jim");
viewModel.items.remove(someObject);

Comment: can't we call it like this - 

<li data-bind="text: Key, click: $root.removeExpertise"></li> ?