# Deleting nexted item in Knockout Js .Map array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i have this ko model where i use ko.mapping.fromJSON() to populate this json below. I am using templates to traverse through the json and i was wondering how one is able to delete an item in a specifc ProceduresToModalityList node. Any insight or help would be most appreciated, Thanks!

```
function ModalityListViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.listModalities = ko.observable();

}


[{
    "Id": 1,
    "PayerID": 5,
    "UserID": 0,
    "Name": "ciby1",
    "Description": "blah",
    "UserCreated": "2",
    "UserModified": "2",
    "DateCreated": "2013-06-20T22:42:47",
    "DateModified": null,
    "ProceduresToModalityList": [{
        "Id": 10,
        "UserID": 0,
        "ModalityID": 1,
        "ModalityName": "ciby1",
        "ProcedureID": 1000,
        "ProcedureCode": "15157",
        "ProcedureDescription": "Tissue cultured skin autograft face scalp eyelids mouth neck ears orbits genitalia hands feet and/or multiple digits each additional 100 sq cm or each additional 1% of body area of infants and children or part thereof (List separately i",
        "UserCreated": "cibydev1",
        "UserModified": "",
        "DateCreated": "2013-06-28T16:10:24",
        "DateModified": null,
        "ErrorMessage": ""
    }],
    "IsActive": true,
    "ErrorMessage": null
}, {
    "Id": 2,
    "PayerID": 5,
    "UserID": 0,
    "Name": "ciby2",
    "Description": "blah",
    "UserCreated": "2",
    "UserModified": "2",
    "DateCreated": "2013-06-20T22:52:37",
    "DateModified": null,
    "ProceduresToModalityList": [],
    "IsActive": true,
    "ErrorMessage": null
}, {
    "Id": 5,
    "PayerID": 5,
    "UserID": 0,
    "Name": "ciby3",
    "Description": "blah",
    "UserCreated": "cibydev1",
    "UserModified": "cibydev1",
    "DateCreated": "2013-06-20T22:59:07",
    "DateModified": null,
    "ProceduresToModalityList": [],
    "IsActive": true,
    "ErrorMessage": null
}]
```

Comment: Have you just tried .remove() ing it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252749/knockoutjs-remove-item-from-observable-array-item-is-listitem-within-ul-which

Comment: You down voted my answer so good luck finding someone to help you.

Comment: i am sorry i didnt know i did something like that, i am new at using stackoverflow. I did try to use the remove and i got the object i wanted to delete. i am just having trouble trying to delete it.

self.deleteOneProcedure1 = function (expertise) {
        console.log(expertise);
       // console.log(self.listModalities());
        self.listModalities().ProceduresToModalityList().remove(expertise);
    };

TypeError: self.listModalities(...).ProceduresToModalityList is not a function